# As (if) 'He behaved as were he a rich man'

Tags: as

> If I were a rich man...

can be written as

> Were I a rich man...

Is this rewriting also valid after 'as'?

> He behaved as if he were a rich man...
>
> He behaved as were he a rich man...

Comment: "If I were a rich man" can be replaced with "Were I **a** rich man" ... you left out the indefinite article, and later on you left out the pronoun "he": the second-to-last example should be "He behaved as if **he** were a rich man..." I've edited to fix these since they don't seem to be related to your main question.

Comment: The short answer is "no, you can't write it that way", but I don't really have a good explanation for why not.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences have completely different feelings about them tough they have the same meaning

> If I were a rich man...
>   Were I a rich man...

using "*if*" emphasizes the hypothetical-ness of *asking* the question, whereas the second may convey more *pondering*

> He behaved as if he were a rich man...

is correct

> He behaved as were he a rich man...

is incorrect, but could be corrected to

> He behaved as *though* he *was* a rich man...

As a side note: "*Were I a rich man*" would not fit into the song as well as

> [If I were a rich man](https://youtu.be/RBHZFYpQ6nc?t=0m38s)

Comment: Say, Peter, is "**He behaved as though a rich man...**" also correct?

Comment: "He behave as though ***he was*** a rich man" would be better or "He behaved as ***if he was*** a rich man", but your sentence would still probably be understood.